# Do Harry Styles and Louis Tomlinson still talk?

Tags: singers, one-direction, harry-styles, louis-tomlinson

[Harry](https://g.co/kgs/LRK5jx) and [Louis](https://g.co/kgs/cVJg3Y) have been [classed as a couple](https://g.co/kgs/e878SY) many times. Out of all the members of [One Direction](https://g.co/kgs/1AXM6L), these 2 had, arguably, the closest relationship, and even lived together. After One Direction's "18-month hiatus", they soon stopped living with each other, but did they stop being friends (or more than friends!)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Dec. 30, 2021 article [Inside Louis Tomlinson's Relationship With Harry Styles Today](https://www.thelist.com/721469/inside-louis-tomlinsons-relationship-with-harry-styles-today/), published by [The List](https://www.thelist.com/)

> While their relationship may be complicated, Harry Styles and Louis Tomlinson remain friends

> Despite the inevitable competition that has emerged between the former 1D bandmates, there has been no notable feuding between Styles or Tomlinson.

> Despite the dating conspiracies and career competition between Styles and Tomlinson, the two bandmates remain friends to this day.

As of this post, that's the most recent article available. However, it is weakly sourced. The most recent specific evidence given of continued friendship dates from 2019.